# Why can i not set a static resource's x:Name in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a View model which I am trying to define in my user control's resource dictionary and set it as the data context like so:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/DMV;component/Controls.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <vm:TaskViewModel x:Key="taskViewModelKey" x:Name="taskViewModelName" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="taskViewModelKey"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

But the field 'x:Name="taskViewModelName"' shows an error:

> Could not register duplicate name 'taskViewModelName' in this scope

I am trying to set the x:Name of the datacontext so that i can still access it from the code behind.

Any suggestions on how i can fix this error?

Comment: "duplicate name 'taskViewModelName'". Sure you didn't use that name somewhere else?

Comment: @Clemens Absolutely positive!

Comment: Besides that you can easily access the TaskViewModel instance in code behind by the DataContext property, like `(TaskViewModel)DataContext`, so there is no need to have it in the UserControl's Resources.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Clemens That makes it alot simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to set the x:Name of the datacontext so that i can still
>   access it from the code behind

First, there's no need to put view model in resources, if the only goal is to initialize data context a little later. Just initialize data context directly:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:TaskViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

and use `(TaskViewModel)DataContext` in code-behind.
Second, if you want to access some resource from code-behind, use resource key:

```
var viewModel = (TaskViewModel)Resources["taskViewModelKey"];
```